How close Flet app on PC with prevent event
I wanna close PC app write in Python with Flet framework, but also i wanna save some value to json file. I wrote on_close_event and set page.window.prevent_close = True  Saving work greate as expected, but when i close app with  page.window.destroy(), i get copule of errors and than app stop working by error and close. I tried use os._exit(0) on the end of on_close_event, but that put app in closing loop and make it worse.
Error:
Error description
It translate to english "Flet stop working etc."
I working on Windows 10, Python 3.12 and  Flet 0.24.1
Not working code:
    def on_close_event(e):
        if e.data == "close":

            un_tasks = dict()
            i = 0
            for tt in tab_download.tasks.controls:
                if type(tt.value) == str:
                    un_tasks[i] = {"ttask": tt.ttask, "value": {"name": "", "path": ""}}
                else:
                    un_tasks[i] = {"ttask": tt.ttask, "value": {"name": tt.value.name, "path": tt.value.path}}
                i += 1

            write_unfinished_tasks(un_tasks)
            page.window.destroy()

    page.window.prevent_close = True
    page.window.on_event = lambda x: on_close_event(x)

I just want to close Flet app on PC with on close event.

I figure out temporary solution, is a little bit goofy, but work
At the end of on_close_event i change page.window.prevent_close to False, cleared page.window.on_event = None and than by page.update() i updated page, finally i start default on close event page.window.close().
def on_close_event(e):
    if e.data == "close":
        print("Saving unfinished tasks...")
        un_tasks = dict()
        i = 0
        for tt in tab_download.tasks.controls:
            if type(tt.value) == str:
                un_tasks[i] = {"ttask": tt.ttask, "value": {"name": "", "path": ""}}
            else:
                un_tasks[i] = {"ttask": tt.ttask, "value": {"name": tt.value.name, "path": tt.value.path}}
            i += 1

        write_unfinished_tasks(un_tasks)
        page.window.prevent_close = False
        page.window.on_event = None
        page.update()
        page.window.close()
        
page.window.prevent_close = True
page.window.on_event = lambda e: on_close_event(e)
page.update()



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
